# Hard reduction formula problem with $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^m}{(x^2+a^2)^n}dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> If $\rm I_{m,n}$ denotes
>   $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^m}{(x^2+a^2)^n}dx$$
>   find a relationship between $\rm I_{m,n}$ and $\rm I_{m-2,n-1}$.

The answer apparently should be $2(n-1)\rm I_{m,n} = (m-1) \rm I_{m-2,n-1}$ , but I'm not sure how to get this.

After this it has also been asked to evaluate $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(x^4)}{(x^2+a^2)^\frac{7}{2}}dx \, .$$

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I have tried to first of all integrate it by parts where I let x^m to be dv/dx and let u to be (x^2+a^2)^n, but after some work, it doesn't give me in the form of I_{m-2,n-1} but I_{m+2,n+1}. Then I also tried to times the integral by 1 and integrate by parts by letting 1 be dv/dx and the rest be u, that didn't give me in the form required either

Comment: Let $x= \tan \theta$

Comment: @Kevin I would say $x = a\tan \theta$.

Comment: @A---B Yes, on reflection so would I :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for integration by parts we can use:

$$\int\text{f}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{g}\space'\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\text{f}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{g}\left(x\right)-\int\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)\cdot\text{g}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

So, when:

- $$\text{f}\left(x\right):=\frac{1}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\text{n}}\space\space\space\implies\space\space\space\text{f}\space'\left(x\right)=-\frac{2\cdot\text{n}\cdot x}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^{1+\text{n}}}\tag2$$
- $$\text{g}\space'\left(x\right):=x^\text{m}\space\space\space\implies\space\space\space\text{g}\left(x\right)=\frac{x^{1+\text{m}}}{1+\text{m}}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{m},\text{n}}:=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\text{m}}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\lim_{\text{z}\to\infty}\space\left[\frac{1}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\text{n}}\cdot\frac{x^{1+\text{m}}}{1+\text{m}}\right]_0^\text{z}-\int_0^\infty-\frac{2\cdot\text{n}\cdot x}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^{1+\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{x^{1+\text{m}}}{1+\text{m}}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\lim_{\text{z}\to\infty}\space\left[\frac{1}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\text{n}}\cdot\frac{x^{1+\text{m}}}{1+\text{m}}\right]_0^\text{z}+\int_0^\infty\frac{2\cdot\text{n}\cdot x}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^{1+\text{n}}}\cdot\frac{x^{1+\text{m}}}{1+\text{m}}\space\text{d}x\tag4$$

Now, we can use:

$$\lim_{\text{z}\to\infty}\space\left[\frac{1}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\text{n}}\cdot\frac{x^{1+\text{m}}}{1+\text{m}}\right]_0^\text{z}=$$
$$\lim_{\text{z}\to\infty}\space\frac{1}{\left(\text{z}^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\text{n}}\cdot\frac{\text{z}^{1+\text{m}}}{1+\text{m}}-\frac{1}{\left(0^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\text{n}}\cdot\frac{0^{1+\text{m}}}{1+\text{m}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{1+\text{m}}\cdot\lim_{\text{z}\to\infty}\space\frac{\text{z}^{1+\text{m}}}{\left(\text{z}^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\text{n}}\tag5$$

When $\text{n}\ne0\space\wedge\space\text{a}\ne0\space\wedge\space\text{m}\ne-1$

And:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space\text{m},\text{n}}=\frac{1}{1+\text{m}}\cdot\left\{\lim_{\text{z}\to\infty}\space\frac{\text{z}^{1+\text{m}}}{\left(\text{z}^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\text{n}}+2\cdot\text{n}\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2+\text{m}}}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^{1+\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x\right\}\tag6$$

---

So, when $\text{m}=4$ and $\text{n}=\frac{7}{2}$, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}_{\space4,\frac{7}{2}}=\frac{1}{1+4}\cdot\left\{\lim_{\text{z}\to\infty}\space\frac{\text{z}^{1+4}}{\left(\text{z}^2+\text{a}^2\right)^\frac{7}{2}}+2\cdot\frac{7}{2}\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2+4}}{\left(x^2+\text{a}^2\right)^{1+\frac{7}{2}}}\space\text{d}x\right\}\tag7$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but on step (5), would the limit not simply tend to 0 as z tends to infinity. Therefore, using the integral you have on step (6), which is in the form of I_(m+2,n+1), how would you go about turning that into I_(m-2,n-1) - which is actually where I was stuck on

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$I(m,n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^m}{(x^2+a^2)^n}dx$$
with substituation $w=a\tan t$ we see
\begin{align}
I(m,n)
&= a^{m-2n+1}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^mt\,\cos^{2n-2-m}t\,dt \\
&= \dfrac12a^{m-2n+1}\beta\left(\frac{m+1}{2},n-\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \\
&= \dfrac12a^{m-2n+1}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{2})\Gamma(n-\frac{m+1}{2})}{\Gamma(n)} 
\end{align}
Here $\beta(x,y)$ is [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and then
\begin{align}
I(m-2,n-1)
&= \dfrac12a^{m-2n+1}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{m-1}{2})\Gamma(n-\frac{m+1}{2})}{\Gamma(n-1)} \\
&= \dfrac12a^{m-2n+1}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{2})\Gamma(n-\frac{m+1}{2})}{\Gamma(n)} \dfrac{2(n-1)}{m+1} \\
&= \dfrac{2(n-1)}{m+1}I(m,n)
\end{align}
so $\color{blue}{I(m-2,n-1)=\dfrac{2(n-1)}{m+1}I(m,n)}$.